# Strange glm() behavior in a function

Tags: r, glm

Please help me understand the re-producible example below.
I am trying to write a function glm_func() that would call glm(). It works perfectly fine outside of a function.
However, if I pass the linear model formula as an argument, the function glm_func() gives out a strange error:

> Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'modeldata' not found

Can someone help me understand what went wrong?

```
# Fully reproducable example
# Specify data
aa = data.frame(y=1:100, x1=1:100, x2=rep(1, 100), z=runif(100))
lm_formula = as.formula('y ~ x1 + x2')
weight_var = 'z'

# GLM works as-is outside of a function
model1 = glm(formula = lm_formula, data = aa, weights = aa[[weight_var]])

# Why does this function not work?
glm_func <- function(modeldata, formula, weight){
  thismodel=glm(
    formula = formula, #<----- Does not work if formula is passed from argument
    data = modeldata,  weights = modeldata[[weight]])}
glm_func(modeldata=aa, formula=lm_formula, weight=weight_var)

# This function works
glm_func2 <- function(modeldata, weight){
  thismodel=glm(
    formula = y ~ x1 + x2, #<----- Works if formula is hardcoded
    data = modeldata,  weights = modeldata[[weight]])}
glm_func2(modeldata=aa, weight=weight_var)
```

Comment: environment(formula) <- environment() should do the trick (can't check because I'm on my phone).

Comment: And the reason is that a formula object always has an associated environment (if the code above didn't make that obvious).

Answer (score 1):

From `help("formula")`:

> A formula object has an associated environment, and this environment
> (rather than the parent environment) is used by `model.frame` to
> evaluate variables that are not found in the supplied `data` argument.
>
> Formulas created with the ~ operator use the environment in which they
> were created. Formulas created with `as.formula` will use the `env`
> argument for their environment.

From this one would expect that you don't need to care about the environment if you use the `data` argument. Sadly that's not the case here because the `weights` are evaluated within the formula's environment (Thanks to useruser2554330 for pointing this out!).

So, you need to ensure that your function environment is associated with the formula:

```
glm_func <- function(modeldata, formula, weight){
  environment(formula) <- environment()
  glm(formula = formula, data = modeldata,  
      weights = modeldata[[weight]])
  }
glm_func(modeldata=aa, formula=lm_formula, weight=weight_var)
#works
```

Personally, I'd do this instead:

```
glm_func <- function(modeldata, formula, weight){
  environment(formula) <- environment()
  eval(
    bquote(
      glm(formula = .(formula), data = modeldata,  
          weights = modeldata[[weight]])
    )
  )
}
```

This way, the actual formula is printed when you print the model object.

Comment: The weights are treated like terms in the formula for evaluation.  The problem with only using the `data` argument is that the expression `modeldata[[weight]]` needs to be evaluated in the `glm_func` evaluation environtment.

Answer (score 0):

As @Roland commented that a formula object has an associated environment so instead of passing a formula object you can pass the variables and create the formula inside the function.

```
glm_func <- function(modeldata, resp, predictor, weight){
  glm(formula = reformulate(predictor, resp), 
    data = modeldata,  weights = modeldata[[weight]])
}

glm_func(modeldata=aa, 'y', c('x1', 'x2'), weight=weight_var)
```